# Fourier transform of $(\vec{r}- \vec{r}_0)/|\vec{r}- \vec{r}_0|^3$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Could anyone find the Fourier transform of below expression in 3D, where $r_0$ is a constant vector?

$$\frac{\vec{r}- \vec{r}_0}{|\vec{r}- \vec{r}_0|^3}$$

Comment: This can be solved by using the fact that $\mathbf F = (\vec r - \vec r_0)/|\vec r - \vec r_0|^3 = \nabla \phi$ where $\phi = 1/|\vec r - \vec r_0|$ and we have $\Delta \phi(\vec r) = \delta(\vec r - \vec r_0)$.

Comment: I don't know the Fourier transform of it @md2perpe

Comment: What definition do you use for the Fourier transform? There are a few variants.

Comment: F(g(r)) = \int_-infinity ^infiniyt g(r) e^{i k.r} d^3k  @md2perpe

Comment: I find $\hat{\vec F} = i \, 4\pi \vec k e^{i \vec k \cdot \vec r_0} / |\vec k|^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf F_0 = {\mathbf r}/{|\mathbf r|^3}.$ This has divergence $\nabla \cdot \mathbf F_0 = 4\pi \delta,$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution on $\mathbb R^3$.

Taking the Fourier transform of both sides gives $-i{\mathbf k}\cdot\hat{\mathbf F}_0 = 4\pi.$ Since $\mathbf{F}_0$ is symmetric, so should $\hat{\mathbf F}_0$. Therefore we assert $\hat{\mathbf F}_0 = f(|\mathbf k|) \mathbf{k}$ for some function $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$.

This gives 
$-i(\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf k)f(|\mathbf k|) = -i|\mathbf k|^2 f(|\mathbf k|)= 4\pi$
so $f(|\mathbf k|) = i\,4\pi/|\mathbf k|^2,$ i.e. 
$$\hat{\mathbf F}_0 = i\,4\pi \frac{\mathbf k}{|\mathbf k|^2}.$$

The transform of the translated field $\mathbf F = (\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0)/|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|^3$ is given by multiplication by a factor:
$$\hat{\mathbf F} = i\,4\pi \frac{\mathbf k}{|\mathbf k|^2} e^{-i \mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r_0}.$$